# interpret acf plot

Tags: arima, seasonality, trend, acf-pacf

I am trying to interpret my results from decomposing my time series and the acf/pacf plot. The adf test gave a p-value less than 0.05 so is it ok to assume that my time series is stationary with no trend or seasonality? Is it ok in the ACF plot if the values are above the thresholds?
[image]

[image: acf plot]

[image]